# newsletter module in opencart 2.1

Tags: opencart, newsletter

I have googled for some hours for how to call module in opencart 2.1. I can not understand. please help me. I want to call this module in template page.

I have installed this newsletter module. Now i want to call in template page "http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23078&filter_search=newsletter%20subscribe&filter_license=0" .

Yes i have done all changes put menu link but still not showing in front side.

Comment: which module you want to call ?

Comment: i want to call newsletter module

Comment: You want to call newsletter module on custom module or existing module ?

Comment: i have install that newsletter module now i want to call that in template page "http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23078&filter_search=newsletter%20subscribe&filter_license=0" i have use this extension

Comment: actually i have purchase the "so popup newsletter " but dont know its not showing anywhere i have set the layout as well but still not showing any module

Comment: Have you done the changes extension required in ` admin/controller/common/menu.php` and `admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl`  ?

Comment: can you let me know what changes i have to done?

Comment: Changes required for extension : http://awesomescreenshot.com/00c5kkmw47

Comment: yes i have do this changes but in front end its not showing and i want to call that module in a one div

Comment: have you assigned from admin `System->design->layout->{modulename} `

Comment: yes i have i have set it